# Create and add net to helmet

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

I'm currently modeling a ww2 helmet:

[image: My Helmet]

I finished the helmet and now want to add a net like in this picture:

[image: Helmet and net]

I tried to create a plane with modifier wireframe and then add cloth physics to the plane. The problem is that when the plane falls down on the helmet it creates a lot of wrinkles. I don't have a lot experience with blender physics yet...

Is there a better way? I want the net to be a seperate object. The net can be very simple but it should have the same form as the helmet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Try it with the ***Tissue*** addon:

- Enable the addon. Create a lowpoly version of your helmet (the size of the pattern will depend on the size of your faces) and create the hexagonal pattern:

[image]
[image]

- In *Object* mode, select the pattern, then the helmet, and in the *N* panel *> Edit > Tissue Tools >* Press *Tesselate*:

[image]

- It has created this net, it has some flaws that you can correct. Keep your helmet where it is (or bring the highpoly), make it invisible, select the net, give it a *Shrinkwrap* modifier with the helmet as *Target*:

[image]

- Go in *Edit* mode and bring some correction to the topology so that you only keep hexagons or kind of, the *Shrinkwrap* will help to keep the vertices on the surface of the helmet:

[image]